# I'm getting "Permission denied" error while installing gem for Alamofire Library

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

I'm trying to install Alamo-fire library in my project. But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Compare with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550903/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-while-installing-a-gem and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320621/gem-install-rails-error-while-executing-gem-errnoeacces

Comment: Where is your ruby installed??

Comment: try this :  **sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master** and then just **pod setup**.

Comment: ruby installed in the "Users" folder in my system..@Akshay

Comment: Make sure you have write privileges.

Comment: Hi, I have successfully installed the pod file by using the following commands: gem update --system
sudo gem install -V -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
pod install